# Action on selecting option from drop down menu

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, action

I just started working with drop down menus. I was trying to figure out how I could make something happen once the user chooses a particular option from the drop down menu.

For example, say I have the following simple drop down menu.

```
<select>
 <option value = ''> Choose Manager </option>
 <option value = 'SAF'> Sir Alex Ferguson </option>
 <option value = 'jose'> Jose Mourinho </option>
</select>
```

followed by the following text box.

```
<input type='text' name = 'CLub' />
```

On choosing Sir Alex from the drop down menu, I want the text box called Club to display MUFC. For Jose, I want the text box called Club to display Real Madrid.

What is the simplest way I could do this? More importantly, I do not want to reload the page!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
   function updateText(){
      $('input[name="Club"]').val($('select[name="something"] option:selected').val());
   }
</script>    

<select name="something" onchange="updateText()">
  <option value = ''> Choose Manager </option>
  <option value = 'SAF'> Sir Alex Ferguson </option>
 <option value = 'jose'> Jose Mourinho </option>
</select>
<input type='text' name = 'Club' />
```

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fkvZ7/

This should update the text box.. You will need to include jQuery lib for this.. You could also replace the jQuery by JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this without reloading the page would be using jQuery